# Xamarin crossplatform Read an xml from online

Tags: c#, xml, xamarin, xamarin.ios, cross-platform

I have an xml file on server www.testsite.com/sample_file.xml

the structure of xml is like this

```
<mobileclients>
    <clientitem>
        <code>SXPFBD</code>
        <api>http://SPFD.azurewebsites.net/APIs/</api>
    </clientitem>
    <clientitem>
        <code>STYPFBD</code>
        <api>http://SPFD.azurewebsites.net/APIs/</api>
    </clientitem>
</mobileclients>
```

I like to check the code input is present in xml or not using a xamarin cross platform application

I cant keep the file as a resource Since it will keep updating  So is it possible to read from an online xml file on the go

Answer (score 0):

Sure, although I would recommend switching to JSON if you can, it is still possible to work with XML.

Here is a code snippet from an app I have developed.

```
public List<NewsItem> GetNewsItems()
{
    var newsXml = XDocument.Load("http://xxxxxxxx.nl/index.php?page=news");

    var newsItems = (from newsitem in newsXml.Descendants("newsitem")
                     select new NewsItem
                     {
                         Title = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(newsitem.Element("title").Value),
                         Message = newsitem.Element("message").Value,
                         Date = DateTime.ParseExact(newsitem.Element("date").Value, "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), // TODO better error handling
                         User = newsitem.Element("user").Value,
                         Replies = Convert.ToInt32(newsitem.Element("replies").Value),
                         Url = newsitem.Element("budgetgamingurl").Value,
                         Views = Convert.ToInt32(newsitem.Element("views").Value)
                     }).ToList();

    return newsItems;
}
```

As you can see it loads the document from a URL and handles the XPath queries in-memory.

It is a bit rough, it could use some error handling, but you'll get the basic idea.